# Execute a command every x seconds in C actual implementation

Tags: c

---

**update**, based on comment,there is a pretty simple solution (copied from internet), but I want `ctrl  + D`  or `ctrl + Q` to quit it.

```
/*
gcc run_every_test2.c && ./a.out

*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int ret = system("realpath uuid.c");
        sleep(2);
        if (WIFSIGNALED(ret) &&
            (WTERMSIG(ret) == SIGINT || WTERMSIG(ret) == SIGQUIT))
                break;
    }
}
```

### --**update**.

`int ret = system("1");` will aslo run every x second.
stdout will return `sh: 1: 1: not found` every x second. can we detect this kind of behavior..

---

now the questions are:

- is `int ret = system("1"); if (WEXITSTATUS(ret) > 0) break;` is ok for detect wrong shell command (like system("1"))?
- is doable to use other hot key except `ctrl+c` to cancel/terminate/abort task run command every x second?

quote from Shell Command Language

> 2.8.2 Exit Status for Commands
>
> Each command has an exit status that can influence the behavior of
> other shell commands. The exit status of commands that are not
> utilities is documented in this section. The exit status of the
> standard utilities is documented in their respective sections.
>
> If a command is not found, the exit status shall be 127. If the
> command name is found, but it is not an executable utility, the exit
> status shall be 126. Applications that invoke utilities without using
> the shell should use these exit status values to report similar
> errors.
>
> If a command fails during word expansion or redirection, its exit
> status shall be between 1 and 125 inclusive.
>
> Internally, for purposes of deciding whether a command exits with a
> non-zero exit status, the shell shall recognize the entire status
> value retrieved for the command by the equivalent of the wait()
> function WEXITSTATUS macro (as defined in the System Interfaces volume
> of POSIX.1-2017). When reporting the exit status with the special
> parameter '?', the shell shall report the full eight bits of exit
> status available. The exit status of a command that terminated because
> it received a signal shall be reported as greater than 128.

Comment: Why create a new thread just to then exit the main thread?  (Of course, that then kills the whole process...)

Comment: And what is your actual question?

Comment: If you want to run `ls -l`, it's probably simplest to use `system()` — the main alternative is `fork()` and `exec*()` (or, I suppose, `posix_spawn()`).  Do you need to worry about the time it takes to kick off the child process?  There are functions like `clock_gettime()` and `nanosleep()` that can be used to ensure that you kick the command into action every 5 seconds with minimal deviation over time.  Or you can just use `sleep()` which will sleep for at least 5 seconds, but over time the interval will drift because it takes just a bit longer than 5 seconds for each iteration.

Comment: Note that mixing threads with `fork()` and `exec*()` is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler based on your suggestions, i updated question.

Comment: @thebusybee I updated my question, question is more hot key to cancel the always running command.

Comment: @KamilCuk now the question is quit the running command using hot key `ctrl + Q` or `ctrl + D`

Comment: That is not a question. Do you want to know how to detect ctrl+q and ctrl+d? Do you know what they do? ctrl+d sends EOF, I think, but I do not remember ctrl+q - what does it do?

Comment: @KamilCuk  ok the question is `int ret = system("1");` will also loop every x second. can we detect it. or I need to it manually...

Comment: @KamilCuk I do it in bash, exit code is 127. If I do `printf("%d\n",ret);` it will return 32512.

Comment: So you used `WIFSIGNALED`. There is also WEXITSTATUS.

Comment: @KamilCuk  I update my question. I am not sure `WEXITSTATUS` is the correct one.

Comment: Suppose the command should run every 3 seconds but the command takes 4 seconds to complete.  Should the controlling code wait for the command to finish, then delay three more seconds before running the next command?  Or should the code schedule itself so that it starts a new process every 3 seconds regardless of how long the command takes?  Or should it wait for the child to finish and if that takes less than 3 seconds, wait until 3 seconds are up, but if it takes more than 3 seconds, immediately run the next command?  All are at least semi-reasonable interpretations.  Or what do you want?

Comment: https://www.depesz.com/2022/11/22/run-a-command-every-x-seconds/#more-4126  shell is too hard for me to understand. I want to write it in C. So run every 3 second for command x. command x will not run infinite loop.  command run, return result to stdout, sleep 3 seconds then run command again. I don't care about how long to execute the command. since there is other metric to monitor it. example, if you create an index in a process, then you can issue command to see the progress, after certain time, the index will be created, so the command will return the same result later.@JonathanLeffler